# ajax request always get error in phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova

i am working on phone gap app for android.i have used facebook login there when i successfully login through facebook i have to request my server to send some data .but i always get error. My code is here:

```
function fblogin(){
  jQuery.noConflict();
  //var fbtoken=window.localStorage.getItem('fbtoken');
  //http://rippr2.softpal.com/FacebookLoginForMobile/{appId}/{accesstoken}
 // var urls="http://rippr2.softpal.com/FacebookLoginForMobile/"+fbappId+"/"+fbtoken;
    var urls="http://ripprservices2.softpal.com/service.svc/GetCity";

        var isSuccess;

        alert("url "+ urls);
        $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        dataType: "text",
        url : urls,           
         success : function(data) {            
                  alert('login response=' +data);



        },
        error : function(xhr) { 
            alert('server error occurred in fblogin');
        } 
  }); 
  if(!isSuccess){
    window.open("index.html","_self");  
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem in your code give above but you dint show full code here because some time happened that js file mismatch or order of js files also matters. so please provide full code here for better understanding.